# How can I display only month end dates on the x axis with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, coldfusion

I have a Highcharts line chart that uses the contents of a query for its data. The data can be over one month, three months, year to date or twelve months and contains a date and a monetary value. If the data spans more than one month, it contains only month end dates. How can I get the x axis labels to only use month end dates? It seems to do it by default with the twelve month and year to date data but the three month data contains both too many dates and dates throughout the months. Code posted below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  // default options
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: '#arguments.divMktValues#',
            type: 'area', 
            width: $("###arguments.divMktValues#").width(),
            height: Math.max(200, $("###arguments.tableMktValues#").height()),
            spacingRight: 0,
            spacingLeft: 0,
            spacingBottom: 5,
            spacingTop: 4
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false              
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                animation: true,
                dashStyle: "solid",
                marker: {enabled: true},


            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '' + this.key +': '+ this.point.y_formatted;
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [
            {
                data: [
                    <cfoutput query="arguments.qryMktValues">
                        {
                            name: '#DateFormat(dt, "mm/dd/yyyy")#',
                            y_formatted: '#NumberFormat(mkt_val, "$,.00")#',
                            y: #mkt_val#,
                            x: Date.UTC(#DateFormat(dt, "yyyy")#, #DateFormat(dt, "m") - 1#,#DateFormat(dt, "d")#,0,0,0)
                        }<cfif CurrentRow neq RecordCount>,</cfif>
                    </cfoutput>
                    ]
            }
        ],
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%m/%d/%y',            
                week: '%m/%d/%y',
                month: '%m/%d/%y'
            },
            labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify',
                    rotation: -45,
                    align: 'right',
                    formatter: function() {
                        var d = new Date(this.value); 
                        var dstr = d.toLocaleDateString();
                        return dstr.slice(0,-4) + dstr.substr(dstr.length - 2);                            
                    }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {text:'Market Value'},
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            labels: {
                y: 8,
                formatter: function() { 
                    if (this.value >= 1000000) {
                    return '$' + (this.value / 1000000) + 'M';
                    }
                    else {
                        return '$' + this.value;    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Since I like to do things the easy way, I would look at adjusting the ColdFusion query so that it handles all the logic pertaining to date ranges.

Comment: Update: I was able to get it to work by setting the tickPixelInterval to 150 thereby ensuring that only four dates show up as ticks on the three month chart. There may be a more definite way to ensure month end dates but this works for now. I'm definitely interested in other, better ideas.